# Can't read files from folders in xamarin portable with PCL Storage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, file-storage

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms portable project in Visual Studio. I'm using the PCL storage plugin - and what should be pretty simple is driving me nuts.
I can't access any files, not on my device and not from any folder in solution.

I need a simple way to actually read an existing file into a stream or byte array.
How do i read from a test .mp4 file located in a folder in solution?

I've tried this:

```
IFile file = await FileSystem.Current.GetFileFromPathAsync("Assets/somefile.png");
```

Tried to access the folders from my winphone device - but all access are denied when trying to get files programmaticly.

Comment: Have you allowed the access via permissions?? How to (in Android for example): https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Comment: Yes i have - although it's on windows phone 8.1 i'm currently trying to acces files. But permissions shouldn't be needed to access a folder in solution.

Comment: is the file in your WP project or the PCL project?

Comment: In the WP project - but i have also tried placing it in a folder in the portable library.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/?

Comment: Actually i did - but i'll read it again to see if i missed something. But i still think its wierd that i'm not allowed to read the file like that.

Comment: Any luck on solving your problem?

Comment: not really, i ended up creating a filepicker for the WP project - i pick a file and copy it to the "shared" folder. I can access the shared folder using the PCL plugin, so atleast i can test some of the mainfunctions in my application now.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a solution for that im my **shared**-project.
With a few changes, it also should work in a PCL Project.
[Load images from resources (shared project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217741/xamarin-forms-how-to-load-an-image-from-resources-into-a-byte-array)