# Local Images to Byte in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to convert local images which are there in project platform wise to bytes.
If I am doing this think

```
 byte[] buff = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Sample.png");
```

I am getting error of `file not found` in android.

Want to know what wrong  I am doing this and need solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by reading the resource stream of your assembly as followed:

```
var applicationTypeInfo = Application.Current.GetType().GetTypeInfo();

byte[] buffer;
using (var stream = applicationTypeInfo.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{applicationTypeInfo.Namespace}.fileName"))
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        long length = stream.Length;
        buffer = new byte[length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
    }
}

return buffer;
```

Edit: for a platform specific implementation, you can have a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233573/7016022

Comment: thanks for the help but I have to load image from platform projects like droid,uwp not from  PCL

Comment: @AditKothari Edited my answer. You'll probably find that useful.

Comment: Sorry still I am not getting the stream of image

Comment: @Adit,I find one thread, maybe helpful to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217741/xamarin-forms-how-to-load-an-image-from-resources-into-a-byte-array/29233573#29233573

Comment: @CherryBu Exactly the same one I've linked in my edit.