# Xamarin.Forms: How to download an Image, save it locally and display it on screen?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I have an issue with opening JPG file in native application on Android. 
I'm using newest release of Xamarin Essentials, there is some functionality called Launcher.
Here is my code

```
await Launcher.TryOpenAsync("file:///" + localPath);
```

My local path is file stored in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);`.

Whenever I try to open that file I am getting error:

```
file:////data/user/0/mypackagename/files/.local/share/Screenshot.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

I found several solutions here on stackoverflow, but I don't want to use Intent because my application is designed to be cross-platform (I would like to avoid native platform coding if this possible).

Launcher throws error on iOS also:

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: ** -- file:///" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's your goal? Is it to display an Image on the screen that is saved as an embedded resource, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50031151/5953643?

Comment: I need to download file from server and present it somehow. I thought that this will be the simplest solution.

Comment: Got it! We'll use Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences to save/retrieve the file from disk. Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher is for opening other apps like Settings or Twitter.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick If you found a solution, could you please add an answer describing what you did? This could help developers in the future

Comment: @PaulKertscher Sure! I answered the question 11 hours ago, below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59634820/5953643

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Sorry, this was a mix up. The *"Got it!"* somehow made me think that it was from the author of the question, which is obviously not you. Since there was no answer by the author of the question I wrote this comment. Sry bou that,

Comment: @PaulKertscher Haha - no worries! 

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Step 1: Download the Image

We can use `HttpClient` to download the image.

`HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync` will retrieve the image data and save it in memory.

In `DownloadImage` below, we will retrieve the image as a `byte[]`.

```cs
static class ImageService
{
    static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public static Task<byte[]> DownloadImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        if (!imageUrl.Trim().StartsWith("https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new Exception("iOS and Android Require Https");

        return _client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);
    }
}
```

## Step 2 Save Image to Disk

Now that we've downloaded the image, we will save it to disk.

`Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences` allows us to save items to disk using key-value pairs. Since `byte[]` is just a pointer to memory, we'll have to first convert the `byte[]` to base64-string before we can save it to disk.

```cs
static class ImageService
{
    static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public static Task<byte[]> DownloadImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        if (!imageUrl.Trim().StartsWith("https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new Exception("iOS and Android Require Https");

        return _client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);
    }

    public static void SaveToDisk(string imageFileName, byte[] imageAsBase64String)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set(imageFileName, Convert.ToBase64String(imageAsBase64String));
    }
}
```

### Step 3 Retrieve the Image for Display

Now that we've downloaded the image and saved it to disk, we need to be able to retrieve the image from disk to display it on the screen.

`GetFromDisk` below retrieves the image from disk and converts it to `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource`.

```cs
static class ImageService
{
    static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public static Task<byte[]> DownloadImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        if (!imageUrl.Trim().StartsWith("https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new Exception("iOS and Android Require Https");

        return _client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);
    }

    public static void SaveToDisk(string imageFileName, byte[] imageAsBase64String)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Set(imageFileName, Convert.ToBase64String(imageAsBase64String));
    }

    public static Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource GetFromDisk(string imageFileName)
    {
        var imageAsBase64String = Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get(imageFileName, string.Empty);

        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(imageAsBase64String)));
    }
}
```

## Example: Using `ImageService` in a `Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage`

```cs
class App : Application
{
    public App() => MainPage = new MyPage();
}

class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    readonly Image _downloadedImage = new Image();

    public MyPage()
    {
        Content = _downloadedImage;
    }

    protected override  async void OnAppearing()
    {
        const string xamrainImageUrl = "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/3701/screenshots/5557667/xamarin-studio-1_2x_4x.png"
        const string xamarinImageName = "XamarinLogo.png";

        var downloadedImage = await ImageService.DownloadImage(xamrainImageUrl);

        ImageService.SaveToDisk(xamarinImageName, downloadedImage);

        _downloadedImage.Source = ImageService.GetFromDisk(xamarinImageName);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to open this image in native application. Is this possible? I have implemented similar solution to yours but I am not very happy about that.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by Native Application? Are you using Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Yes, I am using Xamarin Forms. I would like to download jpg file (it is done) and then open that jpg in default application on Android/iOS (opening photo browser with this photo)

Comment: Oh - ok. That’s a completely different question and a completely different process. Let’s do this: open a new question with that specific explanation, then comment below with the link and we’ll answer it there. I don’t want to delete this question and this answer because both already have a bunch of views and upvotes meaning that this discussion has been helpful to other devs.

Comment: Ok, new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642350/xamarin-forms-open-downloaded-file-in-default-android-ios-application