# Xamarin Forms: Open downloaded file in default Android/iOS application

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms. I would like to download jpg file (it is done) and then open that jpg in default application on Android/iOS (opening photo browser with this photo). Of course photo is single example, I would like to open any file in default application.

I found several solutions native-only but my application is designed to be cross-platform. I though that I can use Launcher from Xamarin.Essentials package but apparently I can't.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try with [Xamarin.Essentials: Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=ios#files):

```
var fn = "File.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
{
    File = new ReadOnlyFile(file)
});
```

Comment: I can't use because of error `file:////data/user/0/mypackagename/files/.local/share/Screenshot.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()` on android and `canOpenURL: failed for URL: ** -- file:///" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file` on iOS

Answer (score 0):

> I found several solutions native-only

Opening something in another app is quite close to the system for a mobile application and there are some things to consider, which dependend on the platform. Usually, mobile apps run in a sandbox with very limited access to the surrounding system. Particularly this means that, if you downloaded a file to the sandbox of your app, other apps (which native viewers are), aren't allowed to access the file.

On Android, you can copy the file to a shared space (see `Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null)`) and then open it. This might be possible with Essentials, but I'm not quite sure, but since we're on the Android platform anyway now, you could create an intent now anyway.

On iOS you create controllers from within your app (for example the [QLPreviewController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/quicklook.qlpreviewcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to preview the file) that may access items in your sandbox. Depending on the type of controller (e.g. `UIActivityViewController`) they may open other apps.

### How to use this platform-independently?

Since you are programming a platform independent app, you'll have to take care that the correct class is called to the platform dependent work. There are several options how you can achieve this

- Use the [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)
- Use a real dependency injection framework
- Use an abstract base class with initialization in the platform dependent projects

#### `DependencyService`

To use the Xamarin.Forms `DependencyService` you need two things

- An interface for the functionality you'd like to implement
- One implementation per platform

Assuming you hvae a simple interface to share a file

```cs
public IShareFile
{
    void ShareFile(string fileName);
}
```

you can implement an implementation of this interface on each platform and add the `DependencyAttribute` to the assembly. e.g. for iOS:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyApp.iOS.DeviceOrientationService))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class ShareFile : IShareFile
    {
        public void Share(string fileName)
        {
            // implementation goes here
        }
    }
}
```

The general scaffold is the same for Android, albeit the implementation differs.

#### Using a real dependency injection framework

Basically it's pretty much the same. You can skip the `DependencyAttribute`, though. In order to make the implementation available you'll have to get hold of the DI container from your platform specific code, which might be tricky. This might be an overshoot for a single dependency, but if you're using a DI container anyway and there are X dependencies, it might be worth the effort.

#### Using an abstract base class

Add an abstract base class to your project

```cs
public abstract class ShareFile
{
    public static ShareFile Instance { get; protected set; }

    public abstract void Share(string fileName);
}
```

and in your implementation in the platform specific project, you add an `Init()` method

```cs
internal class ShareFileImpl : ShareFile
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        ShareFile.Instance = new ShareFileImpl();
    }

    public void Share(string fileName)
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

This init method must be called from your platform specific code. Most likely during initialization. The implementation can then be accessed via its abstraction from your platform independent code (of course you'll see only the abstraction, public methods added to `ShareFileImpl` won't be visible from your platform independent code).

```cs
ShareFile.Instance.Share(fileName);
```

A **combination** of the abstract class approach and dependency injection is also conceivable. When registering your classes in the DI framework, you could register the platform instance like

```cs
container.RegisterInstance<ShareFile>(ShareFile.Instance);
```

This way you can make use of the DI container features (e.g. constructor injection), while keeping the hassles of using the DI container from your platform specific project away from you. The drawback is, that you'll still have to call `ShareFileImpl.Init()` from your platform specfic code.