# FFImageLoading show image after downloaded

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I have offline first mobile chat app where chat messages can be also images.

I.e if I have 20 images, I want to download them first from URL and then to display them from the local files. In the meantime, I want to display a loading placeholder until the image is downloaded. Is there some best practice for doing this? Thanks!

UPDATE: I don't know when the image is downloaded because it will be processed in a queue and file location will be updated in local DB, so I can't await on that download process.

Comment: Kindly check below link. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632849/xamarin-forms-how-to-download-an-image-save-it-locally-and-display-it-on-scree

Answer (score 0):

FFImageLoading has a `LoadingPlaceholder` property for your Images that supports `UriImageSource`, `FileImageSource` and `StreamImageSource`

For more information and examples, check the [docs](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API)