# How can I display an Image object to a content page from code

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my project I request an image from firebase an I stored in a `Image` object. After the reception of the image from firebase I'm trying to display the image to the content page. Running the code bellow i got no exceptions but the image is not visible on the content page.

XAML code

```
<StackLayout>
    <Image x:Name="ImageDisplayObject"/>
</StackLayout>
```

C# Code

```
public void ImageRxEvent(Image firebaseImage)
{
    ImageDisplayObject = firebaseImage;
}
```

I trying to use `FromStream()` method but I also can't find any variant of doing this because the examples are only with an image already stored by the mobile device which in my case it will not work because the image is stored in the firebase server and I'm reading it and storing the image in an object (Image class).

The one and only input is the `Image` object not some string path to the image, because I will use `FromFile()` method in this case.

Comment: is `firebaseImage` a `Xamarin.Forms.Image` or something else?  What specific type (and namespace) is this object?

Comment: what do you receive , a base64 string , stream. What is the type of object . also you can not equate image with image and hope image will be displayed

Comment: Hi Jason, it is an Xamarin.Forms.Image

Comment: so you are storing an entire Image object in Firebase?  That doesn't seem right - you should store the url of the image or the image data as a byte[] or encoded string, not the UI object itself

Comment: I'm storing the image in the firebase storage and in the firebase database the link to the image. Here I'm also researching the way to retrieve the image using the link from firebase.

Comment: @Radu Hi, not knowing the type of Link, you could sahre a sample link in question to check. In addition, do you have a try with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#download-images)?

Comment: Hi Junior Jian, here is an example of link within I can access the image from firebase: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/waiterdatabase.appspot.com/o/Images%2NameOfImage.png?alt=media&token=a8e3ca82-4519-46e6-b3ec-827a7f4635bf`

Comment: @Radu Thanks, I can see that it's a `png` image. However, it can not be display by `ImageView` becauese it's a verified link. I suggest that download it and save in local, then can use `ImageSource.FromStream` to show the image, have a look at this discussion.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632849/xamarin-forms-how-to-download-an-image-save-it-locally-and-display-it-on-scree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what Image class you are using in the ImageRxEvent. however I would suggest creating ImageSources where you get your data. For example if you were using a resource you could use the following.

```
ImageSource UpdatedImage=ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Resource.SettingsIcon));
```

then update your image with

```
ImageDisplayObject.Source=UpdatedImage;
```

Comment: Hi Devlin, i'm using Xamarin.Forms.Image class

Comment: @Radu i would suggest using File.ReadAllBytes(path) and the code above to create an image source instead of using .FromFile(path) otherwise you could try 
ImageDisplayObject.Source=firebaseImage.Source

Comment: I can't use `File.ReadAllBytes(path)` or `FromFile(path)` because the image is stored in the firebase storage and I access it using the URL link to the image. I'm also searching the way to retrieve the image from firebase using the URL link.